# value decode is not a member of org.http4s.AuthedRequest

Tags: scala, http4s, http4s-circe

I am using `http4s` version 0.18, with Circe and I am getting the error `value decode is not a member of org.http4s.AuthedRequest` when I converting the json body to a `case class` within an `AuthedService` with the following code:

```scala
  // case class definition
  case class UserUpdate(name: String)

  import org.http4s.AuthedService
  import org.http4s.circe._

  val updateUserService: AuthedService[String, F] =
    AuthedService {
      case req @ PATCH -> Root / "mypath" as _ =>
       req.decode[UserUpdate] { userUpdate =>
          ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, as the [documentation](https://http4s.org/v1.0/auth/) specifies, that `AuthedService` operates on `AuthedRequest` which is equivalent to `(User, Request[F])`, so what needs to be done is to call `decode` on the `request` part of the `AuthedRequest`, see:

```scala
  // case class definition
  case class UserUpdate(name: String)

  import org.http4s.AuthedService
  import org.http4s.circe._

  val updateUserService: AuthedService[String, F] =
    AuthedService {
      case authReq @ PATCH -> Root / "mypath" as _ =>
       authReq.req.decode[UserUpdate] { userUpdate =>
          ...
        }
    }
```